# How to position a image over the map

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

Im trying to position an image on the map, but can't figure out what the position values mean, this gives me a very hard time getting the right position of the image.

The following is the code I'm using.

```
const imageExtent: any = [10, 10, 10, 10];

        this.map = new Map({
            target: 'map',
            interactions: defaultInteractions().extend([new DragRotateAndZoom()]),
            layers: [
                new TileLayer({
                    source: new OSM()
                }),
                new ImageLayer({
                    source: new Static({
                        url: 'https://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/small-kitten-walking-towards_127900829_0.jpg',
                        crossOrigin: '',
                        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                        imageExtent
                    })
                })
            ],
            view: new View({
                center: fromLonLat([15, 50]),
                zoom: 16
            })
        });
```

The image is currently showing, but in the wrong position.
We would like to use the same coordinate standard as Google Maps.

Comment: If you are trying to imitate Google here is a ground overlay example https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/tools/Google-Earth/kml/index reproduced in OpenLayers https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LomLYe

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ol-ext GeoImage source](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/layer/map.geoimage.html) to display images on the map.
This project lets you reference the image and calculate the params https://github.com/Viglino/Map-georeferencer